# Asp.Net DropDownList problem with apostrophies

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html, drop-down-menu

I'm adding a record to a DropDownList with the following code

```
this.ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem(hs.ToString(), ll.id));
```

This works correctly for normal strings however if there is an apostrophe in the string it comes out in html as

```
<option value="11">Queen&amp;amp;apos;s University</option>
```

where it should have been Queen's University.  I have checked the value immediately before passing the string and it's how it should be.  It looks like it is being encoded twice so the original apostrope is taken out followed by the ampersand exit character.  I'm not sure where the encodes are happening and how to miss one of them out.

Also I'm using .Net 4.0

Thanks

Added the full html for the drop down.

```
<div class="fieldCol">
                            <label for="peopleSearch_lawSchool">LawSchool</label>
                            <select name="ctl00$nrContentPlaceHolder$ddlLawSchool" id="nrContentPlaceHolder_ddlLawSchool" class="peopleSearch_lawSchool" name="peopleSearch_lawSchool">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option value="1">Boston University</option>
    <option value="2">Columbia University</option>
    <option value="3">Cornell Law School</option>
    <option value="4">Dalhousie University</option>
    <option value="5">HEC Montr&#233;al</option>
    <option value="6">London School of Economics and Political Science</option>
    <option value="7">Loyola University</option>
    <option value="8">Magdalene College - Cambridge</option>
    <option value="9">McGill University</option>
    <option value="10">Osgoode Hall Law School</option>
    <option value="11">Queen&amp;amp;apos;s University</option>
    <option value="12">Symbiosis Law College</option>
    <option value="13">Universit&#233; de Moncton</option>
    <option value="14">Universit&#233; de Montr&#233;al</option>
    <option value="15">Universit&#233; de Sherbrooke</option>
    <option value="16">Universit&#233; du Qu&#233;bec &#224; Montr&#233;al</option>
    <option value="17">Universit&#233; Laval</option>
    <option value="18">Universit&#233; Paris X</option>
    <option value="19">University of Alberta</option>
    <option value="20">University of Birmingham</option>
    <option value="21">University of British Columbia</option>
    <option value="22">University of Bucharest</option>
    <option value="23">University of Calgary</option>
    <option value="24">University of California</option>
    <option value="25">University of Cambridge</option>
    <option value="26">University of Detroit Mercy School of Law</option>
    <option value="27">University of Glasgow</option>
    <option value="28">University of London</option>
    <option value="29">University of London, England</option>
    <option value="30">University of Manitoba</option>
    <option value="31">University of New Brunswick</option>
    <option value="32">University of Ottawa</option>
    <option value="33">University of Oxford</option>
    <option value="34">University of Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="35">University of Pune</option>
    <option value="36">University of Toronto</option>
    <option value="37">University of Victoria</option>
    <option value="38">University of Western Ontario</option>
    <option value="39">University of Windsor</option>

</select>
                        </div>
```

It is using a asp:dropdownlist

Comment: What type of object is hs? Is it a string (and thus ToString() is redundant) or is it an object of another type?

Comment: It's a string, although I used a html string from it's creation in nhibernate until that point just as a test to ensure no encoding took place.

Comment: @Hirsty Before you pass `hs` as an item, try storing it in a local variable and seeing what value it has in debug mode. `string temp = hs.ToString();` and check the value of temp. Maybe that will help?

Comment: Something to consider - a double-apostrophe is how it is escaped for SQL.

Comment: I've tried this and nothing is happeneing prior to adding to the dropDownList.  I've also added the apostrophe in at a this point and the same happens, which leads me to think that it is a DropDownList issue

Comment: @Hirsty That's very weird.. I've tried all kinds of things to reproduce this and can't. My page and page source show an apostrophe in display and markup. Sorry bud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can suppress encoding in the DropDownList, so I'd recommend looking at where did `hs` get encoded to see if you can fix that.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything happening to it before this point.

Comment: Where are you pulling the value from? Perhaps it's in the data?

Comment: It's coming from a database.  I can use the same value in my trace and there is nothing done to it

Comment: No really sorry. I can only evaluate the parts you've shown and can only make assumptions about the rest. :/

Comment: Thank you this actually turned out to be the issue.  There was a translation of the text happening onload that was unrelated to the data entered, but this was formatting the dropdownlist.  Thanks for your help.